# Raspberry Pi 3 Prototyping Breadboard HAT

Tags: pi-3, breadboard, hat

How do I get the pin connect on the board. I see how to plug it on top of my raspberry pi through the female pin connected that is attached to the hat. But how do I connect the raspberry pins to the actually board part. Do i solder the wires to the top? That seems wrong. I am use to using a regular breadboard in which I would plug raspberry pi 3v pin to the power row of breadboard.

The raspberry prototype hat im using is - Raspberry Pi 3 Prototyping Board Proto Breadboard HAT by MakerSpo.

Comment: If you amazon search the Raspberry Pi 3 Prototyping Board Proto Breadboard HAT by MakerSpot; you'll get a exact image of the hat im using.

Comment: I noticed part of hat where it specifies the corresponding pin from the pi. How do I connect those wholes to the actually pin coming from female connector?

Comment: the two rows of holes next to the header are connected to the header ... it's not rocket surgery

Comment: You have to solder wires between the holes connected to the header and the section that looks like your breadboard. This is basically a board that allows you to transfer a ratsnest circuit built on a solderless breadboad on to a permanent board. It replaces the prototyping https://rasp.io/prohat/

Comment: Oh sweet didn't realize they were connected to header thanks. Brain surgery or rocket science?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this on Google, here's the answer based on what @jaromanda and @dougie commented...

[image: Photo of Makerspot Pi Prototyping Board]

The holes I coloured green are connected to the corresponding holes in the GPIO connector, so to connect to a GPIO pin, you just have to solder to the corresponding green hole.
Note: one of the holes on the GPIO connector has a square outline, which signifies Pin 1 on the Pi - this is one of the 3.3V supplies, and is the nearest pin to your memory card slot.
Note the generous provision of rails for easy connection of power rails etc..
Make sure you don't connect any input to 5V as this will damage the Pi.

Comment: In case you are unaware of this: You can solder a row of male pins (or female connectors, like those used for the GPIO, much like a normal breadboard).  Of course you need the pins/connectors first, and they are very cheap (a bag full for a few bucks), but you will probably have to mail order them (e.g. from Adafruit).

Comment: Quite - I should have mentioned this, thanks for pointing it out, @goldilocks